# What is the difference between KeyEvent and EditorInfo?

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I was learning about `textView.setOnEditorActionListener` when I came across `KeyEvent` and `EditorInfo`. Here is my code:

```
actv_search_activity.setOnEditorActionListener(object : TextView.OnEditorActionListener{
            override fun onEditorAction(v: TextView?, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH){

                }
                return true
            }

        })
```

Earlier I tried to use `if (event!!.action == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)` from which I got an NPE.

So what is the difference between `KeyEvent` and `EditorInfo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know KeyEvents are quite basic,
User clicks 9 on the keyboard -> `KeyEvents ACTION_DOWN, KEYCODE_9 , ACTION_UP` are sent among others.
EditorInfo is more based on what the "Key Press" will do.
EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ->  "the action key performs a "search" operation, taking the user to the results of searching for the text they have typed (in whatever context is appropriate)."

Comparing the two:

KEYCODE_9 is just 9.

IME_ACTION_SEARCH refers to a key event that denotes a standard practice for the context, like "Find on Page" allows you to type a string and search for that string. The key that allows you to do this sends the IME_ACTION_SEARCH event.

Typically you do not have a dictated button for SEARCH across apps and os version.

Typically you do have a dictated button for 9 though.

Editor
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo

KeyEvent
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent